# Laravel login with one identity and use back button and login with another identity

Tags: php, laravel

I use laravel 5.1 with original setup. If I login with user1's id, and then click back button to the login page, and login again with user2's id, I still get user1's content. Try refreshing the page after login user2, but still get user1's content.

Then I override function

```
public function postLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
```

and added below line:

```
Auth::logout();
```

Is there anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

After digging into the code, I found the problem was in the middleware. Two modifications were made to `AuthController` to fix the problem:

first, change below code

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
}
```

to

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => ['getLogout', 'postLogin']]);
}
```

second, add `\Auth::logout()` at the beginning of function `postLogin()`, then it will work!